# Trying to set up a server to communicate with Spotify Web API using WebDevSimplified Better Spotidy video, keeps on getting an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, spotify

I am trying to use WebDevSimplifies better spotify to set up a server to create my own spotify application. I keep on getting this error and I don't why, I followed the exact same steps Kyle did in his video and for some reason  after I press Login with Spotify, I briefly see my token printed out and get redirected back to Login with Spotify

```
xhr.js:256 
POST http://localhost:3001/login 400 (Bad Request)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:256
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:146
httpMethod @ Axios.js:185
wrap @ bind.js:5
(anonymous) @ useAuth.js:10
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:25154
invokeEffectsInDev @ react-dom.development.js:27351
commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:27330
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27056
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/
```

Here is the code for the server,

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/refresh", (req, res) => {
    const refreshToken = req.body.refreshToken;
    const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
        clientId: <CLIENT_ID>,
        clientSecret: <CLIENT_SECRET>,
        refreshToken,
    });

    spotifyApi
        .refreshAccessToken()
        .then((data) => {
            res.json({
                accessToken: data.body.accessToken,
                expiresIn: data.body.expiresIn,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(400);
        });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const code = req.body.code;
    const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",
        clientId: <CLIENT_ID>,
        clientSecret: <CLIENT_SECRET>,
    });

    spotifyApi
        .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
        .then((data) => {
            res.json({
                accessToken: data.body.access_token,
                refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
                expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.sendStatus(400);
        });
});

app.listen(3001);
```

Here is the code for the client useAuth where the error is happening

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export default function useAuth(code) {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState()
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState()
  const [expiresIn, setExpiresIn] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
        code,
      })
      .then(res => {
        setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken)
        setRefreshToken(res.data.refreshToken)
        setExpiresIn(res.data.expiresIn)
        window.history.pushState({}, null, "/")
      })
      .catch(() => {
        window.location = "/"
      })
  }, [code])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!refreshToken || !expiresIn) return
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3001/refresh", {
          refreshToken,
        })
        .then(res => {
          setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken)
          setExpiresIn(res.data.expiresIn)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          window.location = "/"
        })
    }, (expiresIn - 60) * 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [refreshToken, expiresIn])

  return accessToken
}
```

This line `.catch(() => { window.location = "/" })`
does the redirecting and it does it because it's catching some sort of an error and I have no idea why.